# Куда девается css transition?

Tags: jquery, css-animation, javascript, transition

Добрый день.

Схема такая:

- "аппендю" элемент родителю;
- навешиваю класс родителю с анимацией для ребёнка.

Вот песочница: http://jsfiddle.net/fk1b1swx/1/

Почему `css transition` не срабатывает, если сделаю так:

```
$('.parent').append('<div class="child"></div>');
$('.parent').addClass('go');
```

Но **сработает**, если сделать таким образом:

```
$('.parent').append('<div class="child"></div>');
setTimeout(function(){ $('.parent').addClass('go'); },1);
```

?

И в тоже время, опять, не сработает так:

```
$('.parent').append('<div class="child"></div>');
(function(){ $('.parent').addClass('go'); })();
```

Почему так получается, ведь JS синхронный, т.е. сначала элемент физически "встроится" в DOM, а потом "отстилизуется", и как это решить? Не считаю `setTimeout` хорошим решением, но `.done();` и .complete(); так же не дал результатов. Объясните, как это работает?

Comment: У меня все срабатывает :D и вообще я против самокатов.

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: Благодарю, отсюда подчерпнуть можно вот эту строчку:

`You can also detect when an animation ends: $('#yourElement').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', doSomething);` 

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно грузить анимацию после загрузки `html` и исполняемого синхронно `js`, для этого нужно использовать функцию [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').append('<div class="child"></div>');
});
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.parent').addClass('go');
});
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/fk1b1swx/3/)

**UPD.**
Промониторил вопрос, если я правильно понял, то физически элемент в доме, но браузер не понимает его физического положения из свойства указанного в `css`, поэтому и не срабатывает `transition`, чтобы он сработал нужно [заставить браузер прочитать это свойство](http://jsfiddle.net/fk1b1swx/4/).

Нагуглено [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069167/css-transition-not-firing)

Comment: @MasterAlex, я прекрасно знаю, что с "задержкой" (событие `load` тригерится намно-о-ого позже `DOMReady`) всё работает. Мне нужен ответ: что это за задержка и почему она нужна, если элемент уже физически в ДОМе!?

Comment: @Олег Б, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо, ценно!